# How to choose race in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Right after launching World of Warcraft for the first time I have to create a new character, when choosing a race, how are they different and what criteria should I use?

Comment: See also http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10805/starting-out-in-wow - There's a good point there that really the first thing you should consider is which server to play on (PvP vs PvE) - Playing on PvP realms can be more exciting, but open you up to ganking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a good [answer](http://www.wikihow.com/Choose-the-Best-Class-and-Race-for-Yourself-in-World-of-Warcraft)

> **Choose a race.**
>
> - Before choosing, think of the benefits and disadvantages of the
>     races    you choose. For example, Tauren has War Stomp, which is a
>     good stun    for Warriors, and +5% health, which is also good for
>     Warriors.    Because of this, most Tauren players to Warrior, Death
>     Knight or    Feral Druid. However, with the case of Night Elves,
>     Stealth is a kind    of disadvantage, since it overlaps with rogue and
>     panther(feral    druid) abilities. Therefore, it can be seen as
>     "wasted". Search on    Google if you want further information.
> - It's usually better to decide first on a faction, then on a class, 
>     and last on a race; but it's not necessary. Be aware, however, that
>     not all classes are available for each race. An example of this is
>     the Druid class. Only Night Elves or Worgen (Alliance faction) and Tauren or Trolls
>     (Horde faction) are able to be Druid class. If you have already
>     decided to play for the Horde as a Druid, you have no other options
>     but to play a Tauren/Troll. Draenei and Dwarves are the only Alliance race that can
>     play as Shamans, and Blood Elves and Tauren are the only Horde race that can
>     play as Paladins. If you decide on a race before you decide on a
>     class, understand that your options may be limited.
> - Consider how would you feel playing a certain race. Remember that
>     you    will spend months and maybe years watching your character from
>     his or    her back, so keep that in mind when picking a race. For
>     example, you    may find Gnomes' movements and voice a little
>     annoying, Undead    characters' bones poking though their armor a
>     little disturbing, or    Orcs' roughness a little unpleasant.

Comment: Yeah, it's really about appearance, especially for your first character.  At least when I played the differences were are small and only really significant in the end-game.  I think the differences were bigger then too - eg back then only Dwarf priests had Fear Ward, which made a big difference for various raid bosses.

Comment: The other consideration is where the various races start - some starting areas are more interesting than others, and you're more likely to enjoy yourself. While it's usually not a problem to switch areas, when you're just starting out it can be hard to know where to go. On the Alliance side, I'm told dwarves and gnomes have a really good starting area, while the human one is quite weak (although the second human zone is great, while the draenei one is extremely weak.) Horde-side, trolls and undead have the best starting zones, while orcs are probably the weakest.

Answer (score 2):

Forget min/max-ing, you'll regret it if you want fun.

Take whatever race you can "identify" yourself with the most or which one you like the most according to your own set criteria.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I use to help me choose a race for a character.

1. Performance - All races have abilities and passive benefits that make them better at doing a certain job e.g. tanking, At being a certain class, And there are some races that are better at being a certain class spec than other races. This is often quite an advanced way of selecting a race and is focused on being the best at what you do during your end-game experience i.e raids, And I wouldn't recommend it to a new player.
2. Preference - This is the method that I use more often and would recommend to a new player. This just involves what you prefer i.e character appearance, racial background, roleplaying etc. This method is also helpful when your more focused on questing because the race you pick **hugely** influences your level 1 - 60 levelling experience for example if you're a Blood Elf it's very unlikely that you'll do your 1 - 10 levelling in Durotar.

For you I would definitely recommend the second method but feel free to use the first one if your eager to level quickly and advance to the later level experience.