# What does "genking" mean?

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “ganking”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5727/what-is-ganking)

While watching a youtube video, I came across a sentence that went something like "as an assassin, you want to be constantly 'genking' for your team mates." (Since it was a video, I'm not 100% about the spelling). I tried googling, but had trouble finding something helpful...

Could someone please enlighten me about the meaning of "genking"? Is it a general concept, or is it specific to the game League of Legends? I haven't actually played this game myself, I am just curious.

In case you'd like to see exactly what I'm talking about, it happens around 3:10 in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owrwt97AH54&feature=aso).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect they meant to say "[ganking](http://www.gamereplays.org/leagueoflegends/portals.php?show=index&name=league-of-legends-beginners-guide&tab=6907275)".

Answer (score 0):

I think it was probably "ganking".  Assassins should theoretically be able to quickly slit the throat of random enemies that come up, so in a sense it's "overkill" like ganking.  See http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ganking